# JavaScript form - Ajax is submitting twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I had this JavaScript running on a testing host page(http://www.000webhost.com/), then I moved the form/site to another hosting page(https://www.one.com/). Suddenly the form is posted twice! I have been trying to add the following line `e.stopPropagation();` to the code, right after `e.preventDefault();`, then noting is posted. If I only use `e.stopPropagation();` - nothing is posted either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        var thisForm = $(this);
        //Prevent the default form action
        e.preventDefault();

        //Hide the form
        $(this).fadeOut(function() {
          //Display the "loading" message
          $(".loading").fadeIn(function() {
            //Post the form to the send script
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: thisForm.attr("action"),
              data: thisForm.serialize(),
              //Wait for a successful response
              success: function(data) {
                //Hide the "loading" message
                $(".loading").fadeOut(function() {
                  //Display the "success" message
                  $(".success").text(data).fadeIn();
                });
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
  });
```

I am using `'success.form.bv'`, because I am using [bootstrapvalidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) in order to validate the form. I have not been able to combine the ["Form is submitted twice"](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/form-submit-twice/) example code on the bootstrapvalidator with my code in order to only submit the form once.

What should I do in order to submit the form only once?

Comment: Any cause to post the form after fadeIn effect?`$(".loading").fadeIn(your ajax post function)` move from ajax post out. or better follow the api instructions  `var $form = $(e.target);
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
            bv.defaultSubmit();`

Comment: I assumed this will be the most natural place to post the form.. do you have any other suggestions? I have been trying to combine my code with the example code, but I am not able to get this code to post the form.. I have been googling around for a solution, but have not able to figure this out!

Comment: Have a look here: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/ajax-submit/